# Route controller to Foo/{Action}

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there is some easy way to route an entire controller to something like:

Foo/{Action}?

or do I have to write a route for every action in that controller?

/M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not totally sure what you want todo, but how about:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "FooMap",
            "Foo/{action}",
            new { controller = "Foo"})
```